# Excel 2010 Formula? Search column B for the content in column A

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need a formula to search column B for the content in column A.I want a true/false answer

A1:/EV-16-4014       B1:/HA4/EV-16-4014     true

A2:/EV-16-4021B     B2:/HA3/EV-16-4021B      true

A3:/EV-16-4028     B3:/STUDY-2500/10-ESD   false

Can somone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,$B$1:$B$[EndOfTableRange],1,FALSE),FALSE,TRUE)
```

I would then put this in column C. It searches for the value in the adjacent cell in A, anywhere in the range of cells in B, if it finds something then there is no error so it ISERROR returns FALSE, and the IF statement returns TRUE, otherwise it returns FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I would suggest the formula

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,A1)>0
```

as that will  perform better and is also more concise.
It will return a TRUE if it finds one or more exact matches.

Looking at your data however, it looks like you want to know if the value of cell A1 was contained in the value of cell B1 (and so on). For that matter this formula should do:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FIND(A1,B1,1)))
```